# Own username by comments will sometimes cut off letters

Tags: bug, design, comments

I just noticed that my username (under [this](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/116340/how-can-i-create-a-path-with-b%c3%a9zier-curves-using-a-script?noredirect=1#comment173304_116345) comment) cut off the bottom of the **p** and the **g**.

[image]

I also saw it on another one

[image]

The box only shows by a users **own** comments - meaning, you won't be able to see it by my comments, but you may notice it by your own.

Comment: I'm seeing it too with your username. I think it's a combo of the All-caps username and letters which extend below the baseline, like p, g and q.

Comment: Oh yeh, my bad, it highlights the username of the OP, regardless of who's looking t ait.